# How can I remove the zero values from my highcharts graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Edit: ---See new JSFiddle link below---

I want to get rid of the zero values that are displayed in the graph, mostly visible by the yellow line that represents series4.

If I change the zero's in the data to 'null', then they disappear. I've tried to accomplish this with the formatter-function (which I saw on stackoverflow), but I cannot get it to work.
Can somebody help me out?

```
formatter:function(){
                    if(this.y > 0)
                        return this.y;
                }
```

Edit: Thank you for your comment Barbara. I have now preprocessed the data, so that there are allready nulls in it.
I now have a different kind a weird problem. In JSFiddle, the result is fine; the yellow line has disappeared. See: http://jsfiddle.net/tt1qu4bd/
However, with the exact same Javascript function in my application, my browser still shows the yellow line. See: https://www.screencast.com/t/Cvxuxzb0wdWG

Can't find out why?!?! My experience is that in most cases my 'exact same' statement appears to be false, but I can't find out what the difference could be?!

Comment: The formatter functions are for labels.  If you want to remove zeros from your datasets, you should preprocess the data before you send it to Highcharts.